# Making img stick to top in table with two colums

Tags: css

I have a table with two columns. In one column there is an image that I want to stick to the top of the table when the second table is populated with text. The image is called though a php script:

```
<td width="257">
     <a href="http://mirrorofrace.org/TemplateZoom.php?photo_id=<?echo $_GET['photo_id'];?>">
     <?php echo "<img src=\"http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row["medium_size"]}\" width=\"{$row["medium_width"]}\" height=\"{$row["medium_height"]}\" border=\"0\">";?></a>
  </td>
```

And when the second td is populated with text the image in the first td moves down the page but I want to have it stay at the top of the page. I imagine I need to use css to make this work. 
http://mirrorofrace.org/gallery/profile.php?photo_id=1&interp is one example of what is happening. 
Thanks for any suggestions and help

Comment: Not sure about this issue, but wondering if it's necessary to use tables for what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

to vertical align content in `td/th` , use `vertical-align`: here do `td {vertical-align:top;}`

Comment: Hi and thanks. I tried that but still get the problem of the menus disappearing. Top menu moves above the banner and second menu disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

To vertical align content in `td` and `th` elements, use the `vertical-align` property. By default, it is set to middle, so the image is aligning in the middle of the cell, rather than at the top.

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: @user3486160 how come ? same answer as mine and it works where mine not , tell me :)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your image through css:

```
img{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}
```

either inline or in the CSS file.

If inline, make your image like:

```
    <img src=\"http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row["medium_size"]}\" style=\"width:
{$row["medium_width"]};height:$row["medium_height"]};border:none;
position:absolute;top:0px;\">
```

Comment: Thanks. That mostly worked but when I add the css the top menu disappeared and the nav menu went above the banner. The image file was where I wanted it but I need to also have the menus where they are.

Comment: That should not happen if you associate the css to just the `img` element.